# Jekyll server not working in mobile browser

Tags: ruby, mobile, jekyll, adobe-edge

I'm currently receiving an error when trying to view a [Jekyll](http://jekyllrb.com/) site using [Adobe edge inspector](https://creative.adobe.com/products/inspect). Im using the built in Jekyll development server in port:4000. Furthermore is the Jekyll site in question does not appear within my Safari mobile browser.

**Heres how i start up the server**

```
jekyll serve --watch
```

**and here are the outputs**

```
 Generating...                     done.
 Auto-regeneration: enabled for '/Users/auser/Sites/user.me/code'
 Configuration file: /Users/auser/Sites/user.me/code/_config.yml
 Server address: http://127.0.0.1:4000/
 Server running... press ctrl-c to stop.
```

How can I get this to work in my mobile browser?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you can observe in the Output: (`Server address: http://127.0.0.1:4000/`), Jekyll only answers request coming from the local machine.

To make Jekyll answer on all adresses, use the `-H` option. From `jekyll serve --help`:

```
-H, --host [HOST]  Host to bind to
```

use as follows:

```
jekyll serve --watch -H 0.0.0.0
```